# Linking error when for const class member function

Tags: c++

I have a class, say

```
/* class.h */ 
class myClass {

public:
    void member_function();
};

/* class.cpp */

void myClass::member_function() {
    /* blabla */
}
```

but when I make `member_function` `const`, I get a linking error:

```
error: undefined reference to `member_function()'
```

I am adding `const` to both the function declaration on `myClass` and also to its definition on `class.cpp`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Could you show us an example of how you made the function const?

Comment: Can you show the actual code, including the const function?

Comment: also can you give the full link error, it would be good to know which obj file it's coming from

Comment: Try removing all object files and re-compiling (`make clean`, `make all`).

Comment: I put the code into code pad and I'm getting no error. I don't believe your error is with the code you posted.
http://codepad.org/7zzVzcgN

Comment: @Rawrgulmuffins. The OP said that he/she got the errors when making `member_function` const. You tried the non-const code :)
That said, const-code runs well: http://codepad.org/CYcal3Xf

Comment: @AdriC.S. Yeah, I tried both. I did the const version first.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax for a const function would look like this:

```
/* class.h */ 
class myClass {

public:
    void member_function() const;
};

/* class.cpp */

void myClass::member_function() const {
    /* blabla */
}
```

If there is still a problem after trying this, there must be something else going on in the code.